# Traefik in Service Fabric not getting healtcheck labels

Tags: traefik

I have a stateless service that declares labesl for Traefik healthcheck but in Traefik dashboard I don't see the labels picked up and the healtchek is not running against the service.

I have tried to change the Traefik version from 1.7.6 to 1.7.9 and reordering the labels to see if any of them are picked up with no luck

The service configuration looks like this:

```
<ServiceTypes>
    <!-- This is the name of your ServiceType.
         The UseImplicitHost attribute indicates this is a guest service. -->
    <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="MyServiceType" UseImplicitHost="true">
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Name="Traefik">
          <Labels xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2015/03/fabact-no-schema">
            <Label Key="traefik.enable">true</Label>
            <Label Key="traefik.frontend.rule">Host:foobar.com</Label>
            <Label key="traefik.backend.healthcheck.interval">1s</Label>
            <Label key="traefik.backend.healthcheck.path">/healthpath</Label>
            <Label key="traefik.backend.healthcheck.hostname">foobar.com</Label>
          </Labels>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </StatelessServiceType>
  </ServiceTypes>
```

The Traefik toml file include this:

```
# Enable custom health check options.
[healthcheck]

# Set the default health check interval.
#
# Optional
# Default: "30s"
#
interval = "30s"
```

I would expect to see the labels picked up and shown in the dashboard and the service receiving traffic on the specified path

Comment: For me with Traefik 1.7.12 the labels do get picked up.